# Visual Studio 2008 - How to disable Pending Checkins processing

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Is there a way to disable the "Pending Checkins" processing which Visual Studio 2008 does every time one opens a solution? It's causing problems at our work because the processing of about 4500 files is slow.

Closing the tab didn't seem to help. I also tried the "Perform background status updates" -setting in the Options - Plug-in Settings -window but that was also a no-go.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every time I see a question around performance problems in Visual Studio that are related to having thousands of files in a solution, I think that the problem is not with the tool, but with the solution design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link. The possible solutions are listed here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/bf1b12ec-c61f-470a-a9fb-4fbad708f085  (Refer to the third comment in the thread)

Comment: Thank you! I did the registry hack (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ToolWindows\{53544C4D-5C18-11d3-AB71-0050040AE094} into say into "_{53544C4D-5C18-11d3-AB71-0050040AE094}") and everything is working now much faster. I'm not sure what the "Perform background status updates" switch in Visual Studio Options does because it feels it should affect this behaviour. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option... disable the VS integration with your code repo. I find working with TortoiseSVN (for exampel) outside of the IDE works perfectly well, and causes no IDE issues.

There are obviously other (but similar) tools for different repositories. Since you mention VSS, the Visual SourceSafe Explorer might be an option.

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick. We're in the process of changing our repository to SVN and I think TortoiseSVN should be the way to go. In most cases Visual Studio integration isn't really needed.

Comment: @Miksu- I think you will enjoy SVN over VSS!

Answer (score 1):

4500 pending checkins seems like a large figure (especially when you bear in mind VSS is only really suitable for small projects)- do you checkout the entire solution? You should reconsider why you need so many files checked out. I've used multiple checkouts in VSS (with some success) to prevent "checkout hog" syndrome- where one person checks out way too much stuff because "they need to make a large change". Better still move to a repository that doesn't require checkout (e.g. Subversion).

It looks like if you don't change your approach [you are stuffed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=108919).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is that one doesn't have to checkout files: Visual Studio loops through all the files in the solution every time it's loaded, even though nothing is checked out.

Comment: Ah OK. Just re-read the question- I thought you were checking out 4500 files. Still it looks like VS doesn't behave very well with VSS and large solutions.